# I can't open NBTExplorer with mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to get a color coded world in minecraft, and i looked up a NBTExplorer tutorial to do so. I double clicked on the LevelName: file and nothing popped up. I downloaded the mac version, but it still won't open. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to open NBTExplorer and open the file from there with the leftmost icon in the tool bar.

Just double clicking an NBT file is a good idea, but it's currently not implemented.